# Silverlight on MacOS Catalina

Tags: silverlight, macos-catalina

MacOS Catalina drops support for 32-bit applications, signaling the final death blow to Silverlight on Mac. Anyone out there know of a way to get a Silverlight codebase to run on Mac? I don't mind recompiling or running under a special host. I'm just looking for some way to get a little more time before the codebase is completely replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to migrate to a different framework that runs in the browser. I can recommend [C#/XAML for HTML5](http://www.cshtml5.com/) as a relatively painless option, depending on how complex your Silverlight app is.

Comment: Another good option is [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor), which have very similar idea - coding for the client entirely in managed C#. 

The platform already gained a lot of traction, and Blazor WebAssembly will be [official in 6 months](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/blazor-server-in-net-core-3-0-scenarios-and-performance/). Also there are a lot of component vendors already shaping the ecosystem (Telerik, DevExpress, RadZen).